# Avdmanager for Ionic missing java se.ee with both oracle and open JDK8

Tags: java, ionic3

I get the following error while trying to compile and Ionic-3 app.

```
ionic cordova requirements -->
avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: 
Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee
```

I tried to use both oracle-JDK8 and OpenJDK8 with out success.